# Determining probability generating function for event "$SS$"

Tags: probability, statistics, generating-functions

> Given a sequence of Bernouilli trials, we have $P(S) = \frac{2}{3}$ with $0<p<1$. The event "SS" occurs on the $i$-th trial if we observe an $S$ on the $i$-th trial following a $S$ on the $(i-1)$-th trial. We let $Q$ be the waiting time random variable to see the first event "SS". Show that the probability generating function of $Q$ is given by 
>   $$
> \frac{4}{27}s^{2}\bigg(\dfrac{2}{1-\frac{2}{3}s} + \dfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}s}\bigg)
> $$

I cannot determine how to approach this question to get the probability generating function in that form. My first thought is to let $Q_{1}$ be the waiting time for the first "$S$", and let $Q_{2}$ be the waiting time for the second "$S$" after getting the first "$S$".

Then $Q_{1} \sim Geo(\frac{2}{3})$, and $Q_{2} \sim Geo(\frac{2}{3})$, and as they are independent I can multiply their respective probability generating functions to get the probability generating function for $Q$.

But this gives me 
$$
\dfrac{\frac{4}{9}s^{2}}{(1-\frac{1}{3}s)^{2}}$$
which I cannot simplify to be the requested form. This leads me to think that I made an error in my approach, and I should be approaching this question completely differently.

Comment: Try to calculate the law of $Q$, i.e. $\mathbf{P}(Q=k)$ for every $k$ and then the generating function in the usual way. The support of the law of $Q$ is $\{2,3,4,...\}$, that's why there is an $s^2$ appearing as a factor.

Comment: @Nocturne I'm not quite sure what you mean, do you mean express it as a series and then do a summation?

Comment: Yes. But calculating $\mathbf{P}(Q=k)$ may not be trivial. There may be another way to do this.

Comment: @Nocturne Given that I know the distributions of everything, that seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: $Q$ is not the sum of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. The two successes should occur one after another.

Comment: @Nocturne I don't know what I was thinking, you are correct.

Comment: Are you familiar with Markov chain theory?

Comment: @Nocturne Yes, well, becoming familiar.

Comment: You can create a Markov chain with three states : 0, 1 and 2, corresponding to having observed zero S, one S and two S respectively. The state 2 is an absorbing state and you want to calculate the law of the time to absorption $Q$. If we note $P$ the transition kernel, then $\mathbf{P}(Q>k) = \mathbf{P}_0(X_k=0) + \mathbf{P}(X_k=1) = P^k(0,0) + P^k(0,1)$. The powers of $P$ can be calculated by diagonalization. The two eigenvalues are $2/3$ and $-1/3$, which correspond to the two series you wrote in your question.

Comment: Given the information that is presented in the chapter of the book which this question is a practice problem at the conclusion of, I don't think that that is the approach we are meant to take. I appreciate it though!

Comment: I cannot think of any easier way to calculate the law of $Q$ at the moment.

Comment: @Nocturne Could I condition on the outcomes somehow, and then calculate the pgf? I think it may be a conditioning problem.

Comment: Could you be more precise? There is an implicit conditioning in the Markov chain transition kernel construction.

Comment: @Nocturne DK's answer is what I was trying to come up with as far as conditioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn) already has a solid answer for you, but here's another approach if you're more inclined to conditioning, which I see you considered in the comments.

---

Let $Q_{1}$ be the waiting time for the first "$S$". Then, as you noted, $Q_{1} \sim Geo(\frac{2}{3})$. Now we condition on the $(Q_{1}+1)$-th trial.

We have that 
\begin{equation*}
    Q= 
\begin{cases}
    1+Q_{1},& \text{if } (Q_{1}+1)\text{-th trial is "S"}\\
    1 + Q_{1} + R,              & \text{if } (Q_{1}+1)\text{-th trial is not "S"}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $R$ is the remaining time to get "$SS$" after getting a failure. Note that $R$ and our event $Q$ have the same distribution, <sup>i.e.</sup> $E(S^{R}) = E(S^{Q})$

Now conditioning,

\begin{align*}
G(s) = E(s^{Q}) &= E(s^{1+Q_{1}}) \cdot P[(Q_{1}+1) \text{-th trial is "S"}] + E(s^{1+Q_{1} + R}) \cdot P[(Q_{1}+1) \text{-th trial is "F"}] \\
&=s \cdot E(s^{Q_{1}}) \cdot \frac{2}{3} + s \cdot E(s^{Q_{1}}) \cdot E(s^{Q}) \cdot \frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}

Now you know the probability generating function of $Q_{1}$ as it is geometrically distributed, and you solve for $E(s^{Q})$ accordingly. You should end up with $\dfrac{4s^{2}}{9-3s-2s^{2}}$, and partial fractions will get you to your desired result.

---

*What's wrong with your approach:*

You cannot simply take the summation of $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{2}$ to find your probability generating function for $Q$, as you require the second "$S$" to occur *immediately* after the first one. Were you looking for the event of the first occurrence of the pattern "$SF$" say, then you could use a summation like you did. This would work because your pattern would not be "resetting" with each subsequent "$S$" before your required "$F$".

Answer (score 2):

The atomic monomials are

$
\begin{array}{}
S=\color{#00A000}{2}\left(\frac x{\color{#00A000}{3}}\right)^{\color{#C00000}{1}}&\text{length $\color{#C00000}{1}$, probability $\color{#00A000}{\frac23}$}\\
NS=\color{#00A000}{2}\left(\frac x{\color{#00A000}{3}}\right)^\color{#C00000}{2}&\text{length $\color{#C00000}{2}$, probability $\color{#00A000}{\frac29}$}\\
NNS=\color{#00A000}{2}\left(\frac x{\color{#00A000}{3}}\right)^{\color{#C00000}{3}}&\text{length $\color{#C00000}{3}$, probability $\color{#00A000}{\frac2{27}}$}\\
NNNS=\color{#00A000}{2}\left(\frac x{\color{#00A000}{3}}\right)^{\color{#C00000}{4}}&\text{length $\color{#C00000}{4}$, probability $\color{#00A000}{\frac2{81}}$}\\
\qquad\vdots
\end{array}
$

The first element can be any of the atomic monomials.

The middle elements can be any non-negative number of the atomic monomials, except $S$.

The last element is an $S$.

$$
\overbrace{\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^1}{1-\frac x3}}^{\text{first element}}\ \overbrace{\frac{1\vphantom{\left(\frac x3\right)^1}}{1-\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}{1-\frac x3}}}^{\text{middle elements}}\ \overbrace{\frac{2x\vphantom{\left(\frac x3\right)^1}}3}^{\text{last element}}=\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^1}{1-\frac x3-2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}\frac{2x}3=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{4x^2}{9-3x-2x^2}}
$$

---

**Explanation of the Generating Functions Above**

The "first element" can be $S,NS,NNS,\dots$. Its generating function is
$$
\overbrace{2\left(\frac x3\right)^1}^{S}+\overbrace{2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}^{NS}+\overbrace{2\left(\frac x3\right)^3}^{NNS}+\cdots=\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^1}{1-\frac x3}
$$
Each "middle element" can be $NS,NNS,NNNS,\dots$. Their generating function is
$$
\overbrace{2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}^{NS}+\overbrace{2\left(\frac x3\right)^3}^{NNS}+\overbrace{2\left(\frac x3\right)^4}^{NNNS}+\cdots=\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}{1-\frac x3}
$$
The "middle elements" can consist of $0$ or more of these. Their generating function is
$$
1+\left(\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}{1-\frac x3}\right)+\left(\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}{1-\frac x3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}{1-\frac x3}\right)^3+\dots=\frac1{1-\frac{2\left(\frac x3\right)^2}{1-\frac x3}}
$$
The "last element" is $S$. Its generating function is
$$
\frac{2x}3
$$

Comment: Thank you for this, I honestly haven't formally learned this kind of method yet in my studies but it's very neat!

Comment: [Concrete Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025) is a good reference for this method.